# cannot read xml value via powershell

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to read a value from xml via powershell. But i cannot get the VALUE out

Following is my script

```
 #read xml
    $mydoc = [xml] @"
    <A1>
    <A2>
    <A3 Name="XYZ">VALUE</A3>
    </A2>
    </A1>
    "@
```

I want to retrieve the VALUE. I have tried the following:

```
$mydoc.A1.A2.A3
```

but that doesn't retrieve VALUE.

Comment: I have also tried $mydoc.A1.A2.A3| Format-Table -autosize ... But still i am not able to retrieve the value

Comment: `($mydoc.A1.A2.A3).'#text'`,What version of PowerShell are you using, I'm not able to reproduce this.